# c++ array declaration compared to java array declaration

Tags: c++, arrays

I know in java an array can be declared as

```
int[3] values;
```

or

```
int value[3];
```

Is both form valid in c++ as well?

thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This is not they type of question you want to be asked because it does not show any of your effort.

Comment: @user5709212: That isn't how you want to interact with the SO community.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Only the second one is valid in C or C++.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you should preferably use `std::array` (or similar type) for a fixed size array, like this:

```
array<int, 3> values;
```

For a dynamic size generally use `std::vector` (or similar type), like this:

```
vector<int> values( 3 );
```

The declaration `int[3] values` is invalid in C++, but you can write

```
template< class Some_type >
using Type_ = Some_type;

// ...
Type_< int[3] > values;
```

C++ arrays constitute a large hole in the C++ type system, because in a context where a pointer is expected a C++ array expression decays to a pointer to the first item. Java arrays constitute a smaller hole in the Java type system. Still it's possible to get an exception (run time error) in Java due to incorrect type for an array item. Which seems to indicate that arrays are difficult to get right in any language. C++ raw arrays are, however, among the worst language designs for arrays, so better use the alternatives discussed above.